# cp-kafka-connect does not load debezium mysql connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, debezium

I have a `cp-kafka-connect` service running:

```yaml
  connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'kafka:19092'
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: '8083'
      CONNECT_REST_LISTENERS: 'http://0.0.0.0:8083'
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 'connect'
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: '__connect-config'
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: '__connect-offsets'
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: '__connect-status'
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: 'kafka-connect'
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: 'org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter'
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: 'org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter'
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: '/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components'
```

When I query `connector-plugins` I only get 3 connectors, Mirror - something.

I go inside the container: `docker exec -u root -it <id> bash`, navigate to `/usr/share/java` and I'm running `confluent-hub install --no-prompt debezium/debezium-connector-mysql:latest`.

Expectation: when I query `connector-plugins` I wanna see `debezium`. I only see the same 3 connectors.

What am I doing wrong? The installing goes fine and I can find the debezium connector inside  `/usr/share/confluent-hub-components` which is listed as `CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH`.